# Flat frequency domain response

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have a certain sequence having a flat frequency domain response, is its time domain autocorrelation a delta?
In other terms, is a flat frequency response necessary and sufficient condition for autocorrelation being a delta?

Answer (score 1):

> In other terms, is a flat frequency response necessary and sufficient
>   condition for autocorrelation being a delta?

Yes.
This is because the energy spectrum of the sequence (squared Fourier transform) can be expressed as the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation function.